# Calling by skype using C#

Tags: c#, skype, voice-recognition

I want to develop an assistant software for blind people like [Jarvis](http://ironman.wikia.com/wiki/J.A.R.V.I.S.). It is a C# form application. I need to connect my C# project with Skype API so as to call to some username by using Skype. When I command by using `Call John`, it responds by calling to John by Skype.

Can someone show me some snippets of code that'll help towards this?

Comment: I think that simple `Process.Start("callto:john");` will do the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To start the Skype call, `Process.Start("callto:john");`. You can concatenate "callto:" with the name of the contact.

Look at [MSDN Documentation on Speech Recognition in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh361683(v=office.14).aspx) for writing the code that triggers the call event described above. As seen in the example below copied from documentation, you can listen on a a few words-- in your case, "call".

```
Choices colors = new Choices();
colors.Add(new string[] {"red", "green", "blue"});

GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
gb.Append(colors);

// Create the Grammar instance.
Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
```

**UPDATE**
I'd suggest using `Skype4comLib`. Here's an example!

```
Skype skype;
skype = new SKYPE4COMLib.Skype();
string SkypeID = "john";
Call call = skype.PlaceCall(SkypeID);
```

Comment: I understand the process of grammar building. I am a little bit confused when I write the code that tries to call to john by using skype API.

Comment: @senye Did you try what I provided?

Comment: @senye I added an example using Skype4comLib. Please upvote and mark as best answer if this is the code you are looking for. However, if you're wondering how to implement this code-- that's basic C# :)

Comment: I've checked the nuget package site, not homepage for this, no documentation at all, how could we learn to use this lib? @TejasManohar