# Store Cortana speech commands inside a variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, cortana

I'm working on a Hololens project using Unity where i want to make a Skype call from within Unity. I didn't find any other way than using Cortana for this.

Unfortunately Cortana sometimes has struggles to understand some people here in Germany because of their strong accent.

Is it possible to actually store the voice command in a string inside a variable and use this to speak to Cortana?
For example instead of saying "Call Dinesh" i'd like to have a variable

```
string dinesh = "Call Dinesh";
```

and then tell cortana to 'listen' to this `string` variable on a button click.

That would be awesome.

Ps: Is there actually any cortana API for C# Unity Hololens development available?

Comment: This is a case of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why ask about how to direct Cortana as a workaround, [when it is possible to control Skype directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474912/calling-by-skype-using-c-sharp)? Also, [here's a Unity-specific answer that I stumbled upon](https://answers.unity.com/questions/139203/open-a-external-program.html), which touches on the usage of `Process.Start()` in Unity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling by skype using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474912/calling-by-skype-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Wow i didn't know about the 'XY problem' but now i know.
I know that the cortana solution is not ideal but this is just a temporary solution.
Unfortunately i have a deadline in 2 days and i think integration skype now into hololens just didn't work, so for now i'd first stick to the Y solution until i have some air after the deadline. 

So thanks a lot for the solution @Flater but do you or anyone know how to solve the X problem (storing a speech command into a variable)

Cheers

Comment: Found this interesting article about Cortana in UWP apps [Check it out](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arsurya/2015/07/06/integrating-cortana-in-your-universal-windows-app-using-visual-studio-2015/)